# Scan long string for any potential dates

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which is saved into a database on form process.

I want to create a script which scans the string for any potential dates.

For example:

> "The client told us to ring him back this Saturday" "The patient has
>   an appointment scheduled for 10/10/2013" "Call him back at the end of
>   the month"

If any of these cases are found, a prompt should appear asking if we would like to create a reminder for that specific date.

Comment: There are an unlimited amount of "potential dates" one could conjure... do you have ones in specific in mind?

Comment: Interesting question, but where exactly are you stuck? Post your current code, we can help you with it.

Comment: @Jeremy, probably just [these](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) :-)  If you're going to be storing these as appointments, you need to convert them into a single definite time format, like epoch time.

Comment: *"at the end of the month"*... Hmmm. It's too vague.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I'm not so sure... look at his examples =/

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function, that can read dates like "this Saturday", and the usual 4/5/2014.  You can use a regular expression, like this, to pull out the simple dates:

```regex
\d+\/\d+\/\d+ # e.g., 10/10/2012
```

And relative dates, with something like this.

```regex
(this|next|last|on) (Sat|Sun|Mon|Tues|Wedns|Thurs|Fri)day
```

Then another for months, and "tomorrow", and anything else you like.  It'll get pretty complicated, but you can join them all together like (regexp1|regexp2|regexp3).

The great thing about `strtotime` is that it will just return `false` if it doesn't understand, so you don't need to be too exact.

If these aren't necessarily being processed the same day, you can also pass a timestamp from when the original entry was created.

---

Some things like "at the end of the month" you're going to have to do manually.  `strtotime` reads a lot, but it's not that detailed.